# Is such set always closed? Complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, metric-spaces

Say $f$ is holomorphic on a domain $U$, is the set $Q:=\{z\in U:|f(z)|=k\}$ always closed for a positive number $k$? My gut instinct says it is true due to the fact that $f$ is holomorphic?

Comment: it is closed (in $U$) since $f$ is continuous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f$ is continuous, the map $z \mapsto |f(z)|$ is continuous; the set $Q$ is the preimage under this map of the closed set $\{k\} \subset \mathbb{R}$ and therefore is closed in $U$.